# How to Construct a Single Row from a Multi Row Subset in SQlLSERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, time-and-attendance

I have a situation where employees have time-in , and time-out but they are saved into a single column with a type **[in =1 ,out = 2]**, I need to fetch a single employees time (in-out) in a single row separating with Time-In, Time-Out headers.

Here is the example of table that I have ,

```
CREATE TABLE #Employee
(
empid int,
name varchar(20),
age int
)
CREATE TABLE #TIMEINOUT
(
    id int,
    empid int,
    timeinout datetime,
    [type] tinyint
)

INSERT INTO #Employee values(1,'Benny',35)
INSERT INTO #Employee values(2,'Algo',32)


INSERT INTO #TIMEINOUT VALUES(1,1,'2017-03-08 06:00:00 AM',1) -- (Type 1 = IN , 2 = Out)
INSERT INTO #TIMEINOUT VALUES(2,1,'2017-03-08 05:00:00 PM',2) -- (Type 1 = IN , 2 = Out)
INSERT INTO #TIMEINOUT VALUES(3,2,'2017-03-08 07:00:00 AM',1) -- (Type 1 = IN , 2 = Out)
INSERT INTO #TIMEINOUT VALUES(4,2,'2017-03-08 09:00:00 PM',2) -- (Type 1 = IN , 2 = Out)



SELECT * FROM #Employee INNER JOIN #TIMEINOUT ON #Employee.empid = #TIMEINOUT.empid

Select #Employee.empid,#Employee.name,#Employee.age,GETDATE() as TimeIN,GETDATE() as TimeOUT from #Employee

DROP TABLE #Employee
DROP TABLE #TIMEINOUT
```

Can anybody help to simplify the query?

Comment: expected output should be

Comment: @Chanukya..I have edited and put a select for expected results

Comment: You need to do this by empid, and by date?

Comment: what type mean? 1 is for IN and 2 is for OUT?

Comment: @reds any way, I need an employee's attendance in a single row output having two rows in child-table

Comment: @reds I have single column to store time records, Type = if 1 then employee clocked-in and if Type =2 then Employee Clocked-out.

Comment: Ok got it......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did,

```
SELECT  #Employee.empid ,
    #Employee.name ,
    #TIMEINOUT.timeinout [TimeIN],
    X.timeinout [TimeOUT]
FROM    #Employee
    INNER JOIN #TIMEINOUT ON #TIMEINOUT.empid = #Employee.empid
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  #TIMEINOUT.empid ,
                        #TIMEINOUT.timeinout
                FROM    #TIMEINOUT
                WHERE   type = 2
              ) X ON X.empid = #Employee.empid
                     AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), #TIMEINOUT.timeinout, 111)   = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), X.timeinout, 111)
WHERE   #TIMEINOUT.type = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this? Separate column for `Timein` and `TimeOut`

```
;with cte as (
SELECT e.empid,e.name,e.age,t.timeinout as TimeIn FROM #Employee e INNER  JOIN #TIMEINOUT t ON e.empid = t.empid
 where t.type=1
 )
 select t.empid,t.name,t.age,t.timein as TimeIn,t2.timeinout as Timeout from cte t

 inner join (
select * from #timeinout
where type=2
)t2
 on t.empid=t2.empid
```

Comment: he just missed t2.empid

Comment: Does this work for multiple in and out times for same user?

Comment: It depends for the `type` column if it has `1` and `2` value.

Comment: @DareDevil try it again I just missed the `t2.empid`

Comment: @JackyMontevirgen its working , but cant it be simple so may use it in Oracle?

Comment: So far base on my answer you should get the logic to this so that you can apply it on Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

```
select a.empid,a.timeinout,b.timeinout from 
(select *,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),timeinout,110) as this_in from TIMEINOUT where type = 1) as a
inner join
(select *,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),timeinout,110) as this_out from TIMEINOUT where type = 2) as b
on a.empid = b.empid where a.this_in = b.this_out
```

Comment: Just join employee if you want employee names.

Comment: great approach, I am just thinking that select all then select a column with LEFT join having same emp_id and same date with difference is type as time-out

Comment: the date is important that's why i use to include it in where clause just to make sure

Comment: The problem of your data structure is How about if timeout date laps with one day? you can remove the where clause i guess, This worked if just only 2 records per employee. 1 in and 1 out.