# How to insert rows from one temp table to another in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

```
    ID  LogDate      LogTime           InoutMode    
    1   2017-02-23  19:30:00.0000000    1   
    2   2017-02-23  20:00:00.0000000    0   
    3   2017-02-23  20:30:00.0000000    1   
    4   2017-02-23  21:00:00.0000000    0   
    5   2017-02-23  21:30:00.0000000    1   
    6   2017-02-24  08:00:00.0000000    0
```

The above result got from a temp table.now i want to insert LogTime to another temp table like below.

```
      InOutMode-1 =>InTime
      InOutMode-0 =>OutTime

     InTime            OutTime
   19:30:00.0000000   20:00:00.0000000
   20:30:00.0000000   21:00:00.0000000
   21:30:00.0000000   08:00:00.0000000
```

Comment: It is already answered check http://stackoverflow.com/a/42665218/7012137, its the same, you just have the date in separate column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2 cte's, one for `InoutMode` with `1` and other for `0` and also give row-number based on the order of `Id` column or date and time columns. Then join these 2 cte's.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [rn] = row_number() over(
        order by [Id] -- also order by [LogDate], [LogTime]
    ), *
    from #your_temp_table_name
    where [InoutMode] = 1
),
cte2 as(
    select [rn] = row_number() over(
        order by [Id] -- also order by [LogDate], [LogTime]
    ), *
    from #your_temp_table_name
    where [InoutMode] = 0
)
select 
    t1.[LogTime] [InTime],
    t2.[LogTime] [OutTime]
from cte t1
left join cte2 t2
on t1.[rn] = t2.[rn];
```

If you want the result set into a new temp table. Then last part can be modified as

```
select 
    t1.[LogTime] [InTime],
    t2.[LogTime] [OutTime] 
into #your_new_temp_table_name
from cte t1
left join cte2 t2
on t1.[rn] = t2.[rn];
```

**[Find demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/637557/how-to-insert-rows-from-one-temp-table-to-another-in-sql)**

Answer (score 1):

To insert the row of one table into another table you can write this SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO anotherTemp (InTime)
    SELECT LogTime
    FROM Temp
    WHERE InoutMode = 1  

INSERT INTO anotherTemp (OutTime)
    SELECT LogTime
    FROM Temp
    WHERE InoutMode = 0
```

See this link for more http://www.dofactory.com/sql/insert-into

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM` construct like

```
insert into #temp2
select ID, LogDate, 
case when InoutMode = 1 then LogTime end as InTime, 
case when InoutMode = 0 then LogTime end as OutTime,
InoutMode    
from #temp1
```